# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find an object inside an object, both objects are currently enabled, this is my code which gives the following error.

```
PriceObject = Container.transform.Find(Skin).transform.Find("Price");
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'

Comment: Seems your "PriceObject" variable defined UI.Text component. Change this a transform or   if your transform parent gameobject have a UI.Text component try to add 'yourCode'.gameObject.getComponent<Text>()

Comment: I'd say the error is quite self-explanatory ... what exactly do you not understand in `Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'` -> [CS0029](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029)

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
Container.transform.Find(Skin).transform.Find("Price");
```

has as a result the last element's return. In this case is *Find("Price")* returns a Transform.

So, what you need is to add after *Find("Price")* (that returns a UnityEngine.Transform) a function to get the Text component inside the GameObject of this Transform. This function is *GetComponent()* (that returns a UnityEngine.UI.Text).

The expression should look like this:

```
PriceObject = Container.transform.Find(Skin).transform.Find("Price").GetComponent<Text>();
```

Comment: Isn't .Find() already return a transform object and there are no need to call .transform?